# Windows Phone 8 Message Box

Tags: windows-phone-8

Which is the best way to show complex message boxes in Windows Phone 8?

These are the ones i know off:
Default
Windows Phone Toolkit
Coding4Fun: http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt&referringTitle=Documentation

I am developing a static game.

Im looking to have a sort of settings menu as a message box. As these are quick things that should be very easily changed.

Also, Is it a good idea to do the same for the main game menu.
The rational of both these is that the player should should not be taken away from the main game.

The message box can have multiple buttons, toggle switches, text boxes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My 0.02$: It's best if game menus (start menu, settings menu, high scores, etc) are all rendered in native format as part of the game. That way those menus can have the look & feel of the rest of the game. That being said, that's a lot of work building those extra screens so it's really up to you if you want to shortcut development and reduce development time by using a substandard UX.

Comment: Yes i agree thats how it should be done.
The game is static, and since the menu items are not very extensive even a drop down can suffice. So its keeps the windows phone experience at heart.
I have created the main menu screen in the manner you mentioned, but  due to my strict timeline i need to make an app for launch, which i can deploy and then work on the extra features like custom designed menus etc.
Thanks for the advice :)